# Vendor chunk cachegroup whitelist

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm working on a large legacy enterprise application, over the years migrating it to Webpack 2 and later to 3. Over the course of implementing Webpack, we established several dozen `entries` along with a `vendor` chunk which contained large libraries like jQuery and various polyfills. Using the then-current CommonsChunkPlugin, I was able to specify a list of modules (both local and from the registry) that I wanted to have in the `vendor`.

This worked great (and even worked in asnyc!) since we knew how many % of our users visited each page and whether a module would need to reside in the global `vendor` chunk or only in the entry (so the majority of users don't load modules used in just a couple of rarely-accessed pages).

This changed when we migrated to Webpack 4 and its SplitChunksPlugin. Ever since this upgrade, we haven't been able to find a solution for having specific whitelisted modules in the `vendor` chunk. This is our current configuration:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        minChunks: 2,
        name: 'dependencies'
    }
}
```

Now all modules that are used in 2 or more entries, get put into our `vendor` chunk (which we call "dependencies"). This however isn't optimal, because some heavier modules we only want included  in their entry chunk instead of the one that all users have to load.

I've experimented with various other configurations and have also tried using the [`splitChunks.cacheGroups.test`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunks-cachegroups-test) function but I couldn't get it to work — it seems to only iterate over entries and not their inner modules. Maybe it *is* the way to go and I'm just missing something crucial but I haven't seen any examples of it used to implement a whitelist. The documentation also says "When a chunk name is matched, all modules in the chunk are selected" which is kind of the opposite of what I need.

So what I would like (and what we had in Webpack 2 & 3) is to have a whitelist array of modules that Webpack would use when creating the `vendor` chunk:

```
const dependencies = [
    'jquery',
    'core-js/fn/array/includes',
    './ui/modals'
]
```

… or, even better, a `dependencies.js` file that I could somehow process:

```
import 'jquery'
import 'core-js/fn/array/includes'
import './ui/modals'
```

… and only these modules would end up in the `vendor` chunk, and wouldn't be included in the entries that use them.

Any ideas?